# Composer on Google Platform not available for Python 3

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

According to the documentation here:
https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/release-notes

Composer (GCP's Airflow) is supposed to be available for Python 3 in the console. However, I am seeing  no options for Python 3 in the console.

Comment: This is probably not the appropriate forum for this, hence, I created an Issue Tracker entry, available [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117564061), to bring this to Google's engineers attention. You can click the star next to the issue number to receive notifications when an update is made.

Answer (score 2):

Python3 support is a beta feature in Composer, this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/beta-support) describes how to enable and use beta feature in Cloud Composer.

Answer (score 1):

I was confronted with the same problem and I was able to solve it.
Since there is a checkbox of `Enable Beta Features` on the upper right corner of the console screen, you can select it by enabling it here.